# Unable to create a basic project using Angular CLI

Tags: angular

I tried creating a project using Angular CLI command -
`ng new projectname`.

But unable to complete the creation. It took 20 mins and still seeing the step -
`Installing packages (npm).`

[image]

Comment: You've probably got a slow internet connection. It downloads a large number of packages. Leave it to run. A project I have has 1Gb worth of Node_Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the latest version for ng cli uses `--skip-install` instead of `--skip-npm`